# Custom archive format in Python pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip, zip

I want to download the source code for Python packages using something like

```
pip download --no-binary=:all: $package==$version
```

Almost always this result in a `tar.gz` file (at least on Linux), which is what I want. For NumPy version 1.13.1 however, I retrieve a `zip` file instead. This unreliability makes it somewhat harder to write automatic install scripts, and so I would like to ask if there is any way in which I can choose the format of the retrieved archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip` downloads what it finds at PyPI. For [numpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy) it finds .zip and not .tar.*. So you have to know in advance what formats package publishers provide.

You can ask (or better yet provide a patch for) NumPy team to publish .tar.* in addition to .zip.